# Bootstrap bring img to bottom of div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap and I have an img in a div, the img is top aligned, I couldn't make in stick to the bottom of the div.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6" style="height: 100%">
    <img src="images/tv/Smartphone_Hand.png" class="img-responsive" style="vertical-align: bottom; position: absolute;">    
</div>
```

Comment: add `bottom:0` to the image style and make sure the div is `position:relative`

Comment: `position:absolute;bottom:0` should do the trick, assuming the 100% height on your div is working.

Comment: @Pete the img dissapear !!!

Comment: Is your div position relative? if so, try adding a z-index to the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6" style="height: 100%">
    <img src="images/tv/Smartphone_Hand.png" class="img-responsive" style="position:absolute;bottom:0">    
</div>
```

Use his

Answer (score 0):

I see you're trying to use `vertical-align:bottom`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align):

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an
>   inline or table-cell box.

Because your display is likely the initial (block), it won't work. You could position it as absolute, which you have done, and put it at the bottom:

```css
img {
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/d1/f9/eb/d1f9eb025650eb3ff13a26697ed9994a.jpg" alt="test" />
```

Also, you should avoid using inline styling as much as possible. It makes styling far more complicated as a project unfolds.